# How can I specify the type of a Prisma model when passing it to a factory function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typescript-generics, prisma

I have a service function that retrieves all the elements from a specific model as shown below:

```
import prisma from '../config/database';

export const getMainLinks = async () => await getAll(prisma.mainLinks);
```

Additionally, I have the following getAll factory handler to which I pass a different model each time:

```
export const getAll = async (Model: any) => {
    const docs = await Model.findMany();
    return docs;
};
```

Despite several attempts with generics, I haven't been successful.
What type should I use for the Model parameter in the getAll function?

I tried the following:

```
export const getMainLinks = async () => await getAll<Prisma.MainLinksDelegate>(prisma.mainLinks);

export const getAll = async <T>(Model: T) => {
    const docs = await Model.findMany();
    return docs;
};
```

But I get the error:
"Property 'findMany' does not exist on type 'T'.ts(2339)"

I tried this approach:

```
export const getMainLinks = async () => await getAll(prisma.mainLinks);

export const getAll = async <T extends keyof DelegateMap>(Model: ModelToDelegate<T>) => {
    const docs = await Model.findMany();

    return docs;
};
```

I've defined the types as:

```
export interface DelegateMap {
    [MAIN_LINKS]: Prisma.MainLinksDelegate;
    [SECONDARY_LINKS]: Prisma.SecondaryLinksDelegate;
    [CATEGORIES_LINKS]: Prisma.CategoriesDelegate;
}

export type ModelToDelegate<T extends keyof DelegateMap> = DelegateMap[T];
```

However, I'm encountering the following TypeScript error:

```
"This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '(<T extends MainLinksFindManyArgs<DefaultArgs>>(args?: SelectSubset<T, MainLinksFindManyArgs<DefaultArgs>> | undefined) => PrismaPromise<...>) | (<T extends SecondaryLinksFindManyArgs<...>>(args?: SelectSubset<...> | undefined) => PrismaPromise<...>) | (<T extends CategoriesFindManyArgs<...>>(args?: SelectSubset<......' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2349)"
```